# How to render one of 4 partials with Rails, jquery/ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have 4 possible partials that can be rendered on a view, but only one partial can be loaded at a time.  How can I used jQuery or ajax to be able to render different partials on click?  Thanks!

Here is my header that I want to activate the 4 partials from.  When you click on one, I want it to render a partial below the subnav and change it to be active in the subnav.

```
#subnav
    %ul
      %li
        %a.active{:href => "dashboard-fans.html"}
          %img{:alt => "", :src => image_path("icons/fans.svg")}>/
          Fans
      %li
        %a.active{:href => "dashboard-rewards.html"}
          %img{:alt => "", :src => image_path("icons/rewards.svg")}>/
          Rewards
      %li
        %a{:href => "dashboard-payment-info.html"}
          %img{:alt => "", :src => image_path("icons/creditcard.svg")}>/
          Payment Info
      %li
        %a{:href => "dashboard-profile.html"}
          %img{:alt => "", :src => image_path("icons/edit.svg")}>/
          Profile
```

Comment: Can you share some of your existing code? You'll have more luck giving us a bit more context :)

Comment: Yup, sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

`<%= link_to 'Fans', {view: :dashboard_fans}, remote: true, class: 'active %>`

which will call back to the same controller as an ajax request. You can then create a javascript file `show.js.erb` for example (if your controller action is the show).

In the javascript file, you can do your selections:

```
<% if params[:view].present? %>
  <% case params[:view] %>
    <% when 'dashboard_fans' %>
      $('#empty_div_in_show').html('<%= j render "path_to_your_partial" %>');
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It's good to note that the `case` could be eliminated and you could pass the `view` parameters through to render the partial, but that could end up creating some bad juju with trusting the end user to not mess with things.

Alternatively, you could do something like

`%w(' dashboard_fans dashboard_rewards ').include?(params[:view]) which would be similar to using`case`

The same kind of thing can be used if you're displaying a huge index of records and have a modal or something for each record. Instead of loading the modals for every single record, you can have it send an AJAX request back to the server with the GID/ID/whatever of that object and then render the modal to an empty div. From there you can set the modal to show from the javascript render. This will create a much smaller footprint on the application than having had loaded all modals. I know this isn't directly related to your question, but is also something good to consider.